# How to get index of element in array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why am I not getting the index of each array element which is not 0 in this loop properly?

Here is my code:

```js
let st = "0,1,0,0,1,1";
let arr = [];
arr = st.split(',');

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if( arr[i] != 0){
   console.log(arr.indexOf(i))
 }
}
```

Comment: As someone already mentioned, `i` is the index you're looking for. `indexOf` is meant to find the index of elements in the array. Here `indexOf` is used to search for the index of the index, which of course it not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you look for the index, not for the value. Any greater index than one yields `-1`.

You could take the index directly.

```js
let st = "0,1,0,0,1,1";
let arr = [];
arr = st.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] != 0) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    let st = "0,1,0,0,1,1", arr = st.split(",");
    for( let i in arr ) {
      if( arr[i].compare("0") != 0) {
        console.log(i);
      }
    }
```